# Initiate Chrome browser by simply calling as WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I would like to initiate Chrome browser by simply calling as

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

without defining chromedriver.exe.
To achieve this I've mentioned my **`chromedriver.exe`** path in

```
System Properties>>Environment Variable>>System variable >>Path = Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\NewYork\workspace\chromedriver.exe"
```

Now there is no such error coming while initiating the Chrome Driver but when I run my java file there is one exception is coming

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

Please suggest what I'm aiming to achieve is it doable If yes whats the correct way to do and if no whyn't.

Comment: Try setting `webdriver.chrome.driver` instead of `Dwebdriver.chrome.driver`

Comment: I changed and restarted the eclipse. It didn't work, same error as previous.

Comment: it prints  %webdriver.chrome.driver%

Answer (score 0):

You should download the chromeDriver in a folder, and add this folder in your PATH variable. You'll have to restart your console to make it works.

Comment: post stuXnet suggestion i tried yours and I have putted chromedriver into a new folder "D:\NewYork\workspace\driver"  and restarted eclipse but still its not working.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: public class chrometest {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
   String baseurl = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get(baseurl);
      
 }
This is my simple code
}

Comment: Variable name: Path variable_value = Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\NewYork\workspace\driver\

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using maven then use following in your pom:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And use it like this in your setup:

```
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```